# Incompatible project type .deployproj (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution that contains a .deployproj type of project. It seems that Visual Studio 2019 is not able to load that project. The detailed error message is the following:

> Unsupported
> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.
> For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
> - Provisioning.Arm, "C:...\Provisioning.Arm\Provisioning.Arm.deployproj"

> Non-functional changes required
> Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.

What can I do in order to load the project within Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that you need to install the **Azure Development** workload in order for Visual Studio to be able to load .deployproj projects.

So just modify the current installation to also contain this workload. (I don't know exactly what individual component needs to be installed for this to work, I just installed the entire Azure Development workload).

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Comment: Also faced with that issue for unknown project .deployproj. 

The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=660952&projecttype=151D2E53-A2C4-4D7D-83FE-D05416EBD58E

After lunch VS Installer and turning on Workloads/AzureDevelopment it's gone.

Comment: The _Azure Development_ workload that @Marius mentions above also allows Visual Studio to load ".sfproj" files which refer to Service Fabric projects.

Comment: Thanks. I had this issue with VS2022, answer is still valid for that

Comment: At least for me, when I opened Visual Studio Installer, the Azure development workload checkbox was already checked. That made it appear like it was already installed, even though it was not. I unchecked then checked the checkbox and the UI updated to what I expected to see. From there, I was able to install the workload.